How to get the name of a property from a generic class with constraints
How do I get the name of a property from a generic class having constraints?
I have a simple class defined like this:
class Simple 
{
    //...
}

I have a generic class having constraints defined like this:
class Generic<T> where T : Simple, new()
{
    public T SimpleObject { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}

What I want to do is get the name of the property Type. Normally, I would do this with this line of code:
Console.WriteLine(nameof(Generic.Type));

But this gives me the error: "Using the generic type requires 1 type arguments". Adding the <> after Generic doesn't fix this. I cannot add  after Generic either because there is no implicit reference conversion between object and the class Simple. Is there a way that didn't come to my mind to get the name of the property from a generic class or is this a limitation of the nameof and am I required to hardcode the name of the property in this situation?
The reason I don't want to hardcode the name here is because it is a magic string and if I for some reason rename the property, the hardcoded name is not renamed along with it which causes bugs for obvious reasons.
Update:
In the responses I noticed I wasn't quite clear about where I call the Console.WriteLine line of code. I want to call this line of code outside the Generic Class. For instance in Program.cs or any other different class.

You should rather go for Type.GetGenericParameterConstraints

Or wait... Are wana get type INSIDE the GENERIC CLASS? Then typeof(T) should do the trick...

First comment is if you want to get Simple class

yeap, typeof(T).Name should do it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gXJ5xQ

@Selvin no I want to call it outside the class Generic, so in a different class. See my update in the question. The output I expect from Console.WriteLine() is: Type (which is the name of the property inside the generic class)

As you found out, nameof(Generic<>.Type) isn't possible right now. For what it's worth, there is currently a championed proposal for this feature https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/8480

Just using nameof(Generic<Simple>.Type) (or some known valid type if Simple doesn't have a parameterless constructor) is ugly but will work, and be property-rename-safe.

I just saw the answers above and want to share something with you.
The properties of the generic class are kinda of "hidden" so you can't intellisense them to show what are the properties options.
There is a way using reflection but you have to already know what is the property name like this:
using System;
using System.Reflection;
        
public class Program 
{ 
    
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var genericType = typeof(Generic<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Simple)); 
        var propertyInfo = genericType.GetProperty("Type");
    }
}

Or if you don't know that Type is the property name you can run through all properties like this (on this example we are pri:
using System; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Reflection; 

public class Program 
{ 
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        // Get the type of the generic class with Simple as the generic argument 
        var genericType = typeof(Generic<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Simple));

        // Use reflection to get all properties of the type 
        var stringProperties = genericType.GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)).Select(prop => prop.Name).ToList(); 

        // Print the names of properties that are of type string 
        foreach (var propertyName in stringProperties) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine($"String Property Name: {propertyName}"); 
        } 
    } 
}


It's not that they're hidden but rather that generics don't exist until instantiation and each instantiation is unique.
